# Programmatically scroll UIPageViewController only a little bit

Tags: ios

I have a UIPageViewController with 3 screens. I'd like to programmatically scroll to the right just a little bit when the user first opens the app, to show that he has the ability to scroll left and right, and to show a part of the next screen. Is this possible?

What I really want to do is implement a "bounce" effect upon first loading the app, but first I need to know if it's even possible to scroll the page view controller.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. Not possible.

`UIPageViewController` only allows for atomic page changes via `- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion`

To do what you want to do you might be able to leverage `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` by constructing a simple left/right transition, programmatically shunting it across a bit then cancelling.

You'll be able to find a tutorial for `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` if you are not familiar with the class.

Answer (score 5):

This actually is possible.

First, you need access to the `UIPageViewController` scroll view. In your page view controller subclass:

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.setupScrollView()
}

private func setupScrollView() {
    for view in self.view.subviews{
        if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
            self.scrollView = scrollView
            self.scrollView?.delegate = self // if needed
        }
    }
}
```

When you're ready to show the scroll hint, adjust the content offset of the scroll view. Keep in mind that your initial scroll offset probably isn't zero. Even if you are on the first page, there is the concept of page before and page after. In my case, my initial offset is the width of the screen. Here's an example scroll hint:

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false         

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3,
    animations: { () -> Void in

        if let pvc = self.pageViewController as? HomePageViewController {
            if let currentXOffset: CGFloat = pvc.scrollView?.contentOffset.x {
                pvc.scrollView?.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(currentXOffset + 40, 0), animated: false)
            }
        }
}, completion: { (finished) in

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
        delay: 0.3,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3,
        initialSpringVelocity: 0.6,
        options: .allZeros,
        animations: { () -> Void in

            if let pvc = self.pageViewController as? HomePageViewController {
                if let currentXOffset: CGFloat = pvc.scrollView?.contentOffset.x {
                    pvc.scrollView?.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(currentXOffset - 40, 0), animated: false)
                }
            }
     }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
         self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
     })
```

Comment: What does your implementation of UIPageViewController look like?  I got the view to scroll, but the next view controller doesn't show up for the peak functionality.

Comment: Hey @RobNorback, when my page view controller bounces, I don't actually see the content on the second page. The first page bounces and at least shows users that scrolling is possible. I think that's just a limitation of this approach, but it was better than nothing. If I ever figure out something better I'll post another comment.

Comment: I've noticed the same issue with the 2nd view controller not appearing during the automated scroll, unless the user's already swiped to initialize it first

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody takes a look at this in the future, I've got an easier approach, but it also doesn't show the content on the other viewController. All I do is use the origin cgPoint and move it a bit in one of the ViewControllers of the PageVC:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                self.view.frame.origin.x += 50
            }) { (_) in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    self.view.frame.origin.x -= 50
                }) { (_) in
                    // Do something when it is finished
                }
            }
```